# Binary search trouble

Tags: java, binary-search

so i'm trying to do a binary search through an array of DVD objects by movie director and i'm having a little trouble.  when i run my binary search it only says that the director isn't in the movie collection when it is. i'm still not the best at searching yet so any suggestions to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
public int binarySearch(String key) {
int low=0,high=collection.length-1,mid=(low+high)/2;
  while (low <= high && collection[mid].getDirector().compareTo(key)!=0) {

      if (key.compareTo(collection[mid].getDirector())>0){
          low = mid + 1;
      } 
      else {
          high = mid - 1;
      }
      mid=(low+high)/2;
  }
  if (low>high){
    System.out.print("the director is not in your dvd collection");
      return -1;
  }
      else
 System.out.print("the movie by director " + collection[mid].getDirector() + " is in index ");
  return mid;
      }
```

Comment: Stupid question: are these `DVD` objects sorted by movie director?

Comment: how are the DVD objects sorted?

Comment: wow haha i feel silly. thank you, I had it sorted by title previously

Answer (score 2):

First of all,
make sure that your array is sorted by director, for example:

```
Comparator<DVD> comparator = Comparator.comparing(DVD::getDirector);
Arrays.sort(collection, comparator);
```

Then, use the binary search of the JDK:

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(collection, new DVD() {
  @Override
  String getDirector() {
    return key;
  }
}, comparator);
```

*Thanks [@Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) for simplifying my clumsy  lambda!*